# How to get around auth level when testing API on laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, postman

I am using the basic Auth from laravel that you get from running the following command.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I have an API written so that the backend on the server can update/create services and statuses. The issue i'm running into is that the Admin also has a UI on the web app and can create a service, or update its status manually. Therefore, I have an Auth level on the methods where you have to be logged in to use them.

Now when I call the method in postman it redirects me to the login page, I was wondering if there was a way around this Auth level strictly for an API?

I was told of a way to do pre-request scripts directly in postman but i'm fairly lost when it comes to the whole java script part of that and feel like there is an easier way to do it. I also already tried to do 'basic auth' with the username and password, it didnt seem to work though.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Edit: Here is the screenshot from my [header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TXTh.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming if you have the API in place you have an `api_token` set for the specific user. You can use that inside `Postman` in one of two ways.

1. You will goto the Headers tab and add:

`Key: Authorization`

`Value: Bearer API_TOKEN_VALUE`

*Edited:* Added the screenshot of postman

[image]

2. You can amend the url for the request and add the token:

`url_to_api_endpoint?api_token=API_TOKEN_VALUE`

On the api routes if you have `->middleware('auth:api')` Laravel will read the authorization token from the header or using the query parameter and check it to the database value.

**Adding the api_token to the user table**

If you don't have an `api_token` field in your user table then add one. It is not the same as `remember_token`, they are different. So add to your user migration the following:

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

You will need to update the users `api_token` using something like the following:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->update(['api_token' => str_random(60)]);
```

That 60 character string you will use where I put `VALUE_OF_TOKEN_FROM_DB`

Comment: Testing it now, will let you know!

Comment: I added it via the postman authentication tab, using the variable session as the token so my value is Bearer {{session}}. Still not working because the session value is still empty. working on trying to get the token from DB into the session variable now.

Comment: Don't do it there, I added a screenshot. Add it under the headers or to test just as part of the api_request url, ie. ```api_request?api_token=VALUE_FROM_DB```

Comment: ill add screenshots of what my header looks like, also to clear up any confusion the column name in my database is remember_token. so what you're saying is dont use the postman Auth? and just manually put the token variable in the header?

Comment: Where you said I would need to update the users api_token, where would I do this at??

Comment: That is another question, but for your needs you can use ```php artisan tinker``` or just add something in a dummy route.